# Counting number of spaces before a string in Excel

Tags: excel

A program that exports to Excel creates a file with an indented list in a single column like this:

```
Column A
 First Text
  Second Text
   Third Text
  Fourth Text
 Fifth Text
```

How can I create a function in excel that counts the number of white spaces before the string of text?

So as to return: 1 for the first text row and 3 for the for the thirst row, etc in this example.

Preferably seeking a non-VBA solution.

Comment: Is there any whitespace *after* each string of text?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`TRIM` doesn't help here because it removes double spaces also between words.

The main idea is to find the FIRST letter in the trimmed string and find its position in the original string:

```
=FIND(LEFT(TRIM(A1),1),A1)-1
```

Comment: @Noobacode Sure. I always test what I post here as an answer.

Comment: Oh that's very very good! Well done. Note that some Excel regions use `,` in place of `;`.

Comment: @valex My apologies, Bathsheba is right, I needed to use `,`.  Well done, sir -- that is a brilliant solution.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this function in Ms Excel itself:

```
=LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",""))
```

This would apply if the results are in a **single cell**. If it is for a whole row/column, just drag the formula accordingly.

Comment: Unfortunately this will eliminate spaces between words too.

Comment: @Bathsheba, that's a valid point. However, considering that the goal is to find the number of spaces, I feel that as long as the resulting cell is in a different row/column, it wouldn't compromise the data at hand.

Comment: But wouldn’t it also count spaces between words or trailing?

Answer (score 2):

Try below:

`=FIND(" ",A1,1)-1`

It calculates the position of the first found whitespace character in a cell and reduces it by 1 to reflect number of characters before that position.

Comment: Doesn't work when there are any _other_ spaces besides the initial ones we are trying to count :)

Answer (score 0):

As per http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/61485-counting-spaces.html, you may try:

```
=LEN(Cell)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(Cell," ",""))
```

where Cell is your target cell (i.e. A1, B1, D3, etc.).

My example:

```
B8: =LEN(F8)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(F8," ",""))

F8: [ this is a test    ]

produces 4 in B8.
```

The above method will count spaces before the string if any were inserted, between individual words and after the string, if any were inserted.  It won't count available space that does not have an actual white space character.  So, if I inserted two spaces after test in the above example, the total count would be raised to 6.

Comment: What about spaces between words and possible in the end of string?

Comment: @valex This counts spaces before the first string and between all the strings.  It doesn't count spaces afterwards unless you insert them using spacebar (as in, it doesn't count the space left between last character and the right edge of the cell, since there are no actual characters).

Comment: AME asks for "number of white spaces before the string". Your example should produce `1` space before "this" not `4`

Answer (score 0):

As has been pointed out in the other answers, you can't really use `TRIM` or `SUBSTITUTE` as potential spaces in between words or at the end will give you the wrong result.

However, this formula will work:

```
=MATCH(TRUE,MID(A1,COLUMN($A$1:$J$1),1)<>" ",0)-1
```

You need to enter it as an array formula, i.e. press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Enter</kbd> instead of <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

In case you expect more than 10 spaces, replace the `$J` with a column letter further down in the alphabet!

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution. If the left 5 characters equals "_____" (5 blank spaces), then return 5, else look for 4 spaces, and so on.

```
=IF(LEFT(B1,5)="     ",5,IF(LEFT(B1,4)="    ",4,IF(LEFT(B1,3)="   ",3,IF(LEFT(B1,2)="  ",2,1))))
```

Comment: Too messy, and so therefore doesn't work when there are e.g. 6 initial spaces. The elegant solution of @valex above is neat and elegant, so it works even for e.g. two hundred and nineteen initial spaces :)

Answer (score 0):

You almost got it with LEN + TRIM in answers before, you only need to combine both:

```
=LEN(Cell)-LEN(TRIM(Cell))
```

Comment: Needs ltrim not just trim to avoid counting trailing space

Answer (score 0):

If it is Indented you could create a Personal Function like this:

```
Function IndentLevel(Cell As Range)
'This function returns the indentation of a cell content
Application.Volatile
'With "Application.Volatile" you can make sure, that the function will be 
 recalculated once the worksheet is recalculated
'for example, when you press F9 (Windows) or press enter in a cell
IndentLevel = Cell.IndentLevel
'Return the IndentLevel
End Function
```

This will work only if it is Indented, you can see this property in the Cell Format -> Alignment.

After This you could see the Indentation Level.

[image]